# ShareThis wordpress show share options on button click

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, sharethis, socialshare

Im using the share this wordpress plugin, currently i have a button which says share, when this is pressed i would like the share options to display but im not sure how to go about this...the only code i have right now is the button.

```
<div class="su-service-title" style="padding-left:30px;min-height:16px;line-  height:16px"><i class="fa fa-share-alt" style="font-size:16px;color:#575756"></i> Share</div>
```

When the user clicks this button how can i show the sharing options?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Setting the onhover property to false should work for you:

stLight.options({
    publisher:"c7a25472-030e-48ce-b630-a71f99cc53d9",
    onhover: false
});

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but were would i put this?

Comment: put before closing the <head> tag within <script> tag with your publisher key provided